# Is there a way to know which keys or functions I used most?

Tags: key-bindings

If I can find out which keys I used most, I may create a macro for it; if I can find out which function I used most yet not binded, I can bind it to a key. This may improve efficiency. Is there a way to get these statistics knowledge?

Answer (score 6):

#### `smex` users

If you use [`smex`](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex/blob/master/README.markdown), the `smex-show-unbound-commands` command does exactly that; show the commands that you use frequently using `M-x` (the suggested `smex` binding) but have yet to be bound to a key binding.

Comment: Ha, added the same answer at the same time. I'l just +1 yours and drop mine.

Comment: @glucas: good karma for good sportsmanship!

Answer (score 5):

I used to use [keyfreq](https://github.com/dacap/keyfreq).
It was good, but eventually I switched it off and went back
to using my intuition.

Answer (score 4):

You can view the last 300 keystrokes with `C-h l` calling the `view-lossage` function. Inspect the displayed buffer to see what 300 keys you last hit.

If you call `describe-function` then `view-lossage` you will see that you can also use the `open-dribble-file` function to start writing (record) all characters you type to a file.

Comment: (-1)  1. 300 is **hard-coded** (in function `recent-keys`). It is not just a default value. 2. `C-h l` does **not** tell you anything about "*what keys you hit the most*". It tells you only what the last 300 keys you used were.

Comment: @Drew Answer edited.

Comment: (+1) Looks better. Glad you mentioned `open-dribble-file`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761401/for-emacs-how-to-store-what-view-lossage-collects-into-an-external-file may also be of interest.